# Loop on list causes IndexError - Python

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, run-length-encoding

I am trying to calculate the area of a file with RLE (run Length Encoding) format numbers using PYTHON. I am having trouble with my FOR and IF statements.

[image]

I am trying to calculate the area of cells containing the value 201.

> My current error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\2016-2017\Fall2016\SpatialDataStructures\Labs\Lab4\Area_Calc_from_RLE.py", line 68, in <module>
    if cellValuesAsIntList[i] == 201:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

> Here is the file I am working with:

```
ncols         40
nrows         40
xllcorner     -2.3036649208516
yllcorner     -1.1518324594945
cellsize      25
NODATA_value  -9999
13, 0, 1, 201, 26, 0, 1, 3, 12, 0, 1, 201, 39, 0, 1, 201, 39, 0, 1, 201, 39, 0, 2, 201, 33, 0, 4, 501, 2, 0, 2, 201, 32, 0, 4, 501, 3, 0, 3, 201, 29, 0, 5, 501, 5, 0, 2, 201, 26, 0, 7, 501, 6, 0, 1, 201, 25, 0, 8, 501, 6, 0, 1, 201, 25, 0, 7, 501, 7, 0, 1, 201, 25, 0, 6, 501, 8, 0, 1, 201, 25, 0, 6, 501, 8, 0, 1, 201, 6, 0, 4, 102, 15, 0, 7, 501, 7, 0, 1, 201, 6, 0, 6, 102, 14, 0, 7, 501, 5, 0, 2, 201, 6, 0, 6, 102, 15, 0, 6, 501, 5, 0, 1, 201, 7, 0, 5, 102, 16, 0, 6, 501, 5, 0, 1, 201, 7, 0, 4, 102, 18, 0, 8, 501, 2, 0, 5, 201, 3, 0, 3, 102, 19, 0, 9, 501, 5, 0, 2, 201, 25, 0, 8, 501, 6, 0, 1, 201, 29, 0, 4, 501, 6, 0, 1, 201, 29, 0, 4, 501, 6, 0, 1, 201, 9, 0, 1, 501, 5, 102, 15, 0, 2, 501, 7, 0, 1, 201, 9, 0, 6, 102, 23, 0, 2, 201, 8, 0, 1, 501, 6, 102, 3, 0, 4, 202, 15, 0, 2, 201, 4, 0, 6, 501, 6, 102, 2, 0, 2, 202, 2, 0, 8, 202, 5, 0, 4, 201, 4, 0, 8, 501, 4, 102, 3, 0, 1, 202, 5, 0, 2, 202, 3, 0, 6, 202, 1, 201, 7, 0, 8, 501, 2, 102, 1, 501, 21, 0, 1, 201, 6, 0, 11, 501, 22, 0, 1, 201, 6, 0, 8, 501, 25, 0, 1, 201, 6, 0, 8, 501, 25, 0, 1, 201, 1, 101, 5, 0, 8, 501, 25, 0, 1, 201, 1, 101, 5, 0, 8, 501, 14, 0, 3, 101, 8, 0, 1, 201, 1, 101, 5, 0, 11, 501, 12, 0, 4, 101, 6, 0, 2, 201, 1, 101, 4, 0, 12, 501, 11, 0, 4, 101, 6, 0, 1, 101, 1, 201, 1, 101, 4, 0, 12, 501, 21, 0, 1, 101, 1, 201, 5, 0, 11, 501, 23, 0, 1, 201, 5, 0, 8, 501, 26, 0, 1, 201, 5, 0, 8, 501, 26, 0, 1, 201, 5, 0, 7, 501, 27, 0, 1, 201, 5, 0, 8, 501, 8, 0
```

> This is my code:

```
fi = open(r'D:\2016-2017\Fall2016\SpatialDataStructures\Labs\Lab4\Data\AsRLE.txt','r')
fileLines = fi.readlines()
fi.close
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#Populated variables required for code from fileLines variable  
cellValuesAsString = []
lineNum = 0
for line in fileLines: # for each line the FileLines List
  # get number of cols, ncols, i.e. the 1st line in the file
  if lineNum == 0:
    ncols = int(line[14:])
  # get number of rows, nrows, i.e. the 2nd line in the file
  elif lineNum == 1:
    nrows = int(line[14:])
  # get cell size, cellsize, i.e. the 5th line in the file
  elif lineNum == 4:
    cellsize = int(line[14:])
  # get cell values in RLE format as String, , i.e. the 7th line in the file
  elif lineNum == 6:
    cellValuesAsString = line
  lineNum = lineNum + 1

# removes spaces
cellValuesAsString = cellValuesAsString.replace(" ", "")

# convert string into a list of strings split by comma
cellValuesAsStringList = cellValuesAsString.split(',')

# convert strings to integers
cellValuesAsIntList = cellValuesAsStringList
for index, item in enumerate(cellValuesAsStringList):
    cellValuesAsIntList[index] = int(cellValuesAsStringList[index])
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#THIS IS WHERE YOU WRITE YOUR CODE

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
cellCode = 201
codeArea = 0

area = 0
npixels = 0
i = 1

for cellValuesAsIntList in line:
  if cellValuesAsIntList[i] == 201:
    b = cellValuesAsIntList[i-1]
    npixels = npixels + b
  else:
    i=i+2




print npixles
print "Area: " + npixels * cellSize
```

Comment: Where is `line` defined again?

Comment: @kiran.koduru well, I am trying to figure out what to put there. I want to loop through the array. I am having trouble which values to put in the FOR statement.

Comment: You need to build your program step by step. Can't paste a blob of text and ask someone to write it for you. The `for` loop is used to iterate through `iterables` in python `strings`, `list`, `tuples`, `dictionaries` are all iterables.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a great effort.  Your issue is that you are running out of indices, which raises the `IndexError`.  Although your situation requires each item to be somewhat index aware, luckily you only have to poll the previously iterated value.

For such situations, try tracking the previous value:

```
npixels = 0
cells = cellValuesAsIntList                         # for clarity

prev = None
for cell in cells:
    if cell == 201:
        npixels += prev                             # increment operator
    prev = cell
```

As a rule of thumb, **avoid mutating indices *and* iteration**.  While this is not your direct problem, this practice can cause many side effects.  If possible, directly iterate a sequence and work with each iterated item.  Avoid mutating indices by other means, e.g. reverse iteration, mutating a copied sequence or use comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have:

```
>>> rle=[2,5,1,8,6,9,3,30,6,22,2,12]
```

You can turn that into run length tuples like so:

```
>>> zip(*[iter(rle)]*2)
[(2, 5), (1, 8), (6, 9), (3, 30), (6, 22), (2, 12)]
```

Then you can filter for the values containing some target value (I will use `2` even though you mention `201` as a target because your example does not have `201` in it):

```
>>> filter(lambda t: t[0]==2, zip(*[iter(rle)]*2))
[(2, 5), (2, 12)]
```

Then apply that to your file:

```
with open(file_name) as f_in:
   for line in f_in:
       li_as_ints=map(int, line.split(","))
       fl=filter(lambda t: t[0]==201, zip(*[iter(li_as_ints)]*2))
       # produces all the values, expanded, with 121 as value...
```

Please *don't* do something along these lines:

```
fh=open(a_file_name)
lines=fh.readlines()
for line in lines:
   #process a line
```

You are unnecessarily reading the entire file.

**Instead do**:

```
with open(a_file_name) as f_in:
   for line in f_in:
     # process a line
```

Comment: Elegant.  In Python 3, you would need `>>> list(zip(*[iter(rle)]*2))`.

Comment: Only to display the results. For the final loop, of course, you can just iterate over the result of `filter`...

Comment: You are right, although for clarity, to get the result you posted, `list()` would be needed.